# Duplicate column in dataset

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have to load a response from an xml file into a dataset. I have written the following code in c#

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.LoadXml(Response);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
DataTable EquoteRes = ds.Tables["EQuote"];
```

When I debug, I get this error:

> A column named 'ChildNodes' already belongs to this DataTable:
>   cannot set a nested table name to the same name.

xml file is as below

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: What language is that? Please add the right tag for it to your question.

Comment: Could you attach the xml you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

Very Similar discussion on the asp.net forum [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1220157.aspx/1?Duplicate%20name%20Exception).

And for more information [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/d9cc3c96-3aec-4803-867a-227a1bef0cb0) can also be referred.